# How to use Scikit Learn dictvectorizer to get encoded dataframe from dense dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, encode, dictvectorizer

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   user  item  affinity
0     1    13       0.1
1     2    11       0.4
2     3    14       0.9
3     4    12       1.0
```

From this I want to create an encoded dataset (for `fastFM`) as follows:

```
  user1 user2 user4 user4 item11 item12 item13 item14 affinity
    1     0     0     0     0      0      1      0       0.1
    0     1     0     0     1      0      0      0       0.4
    0     0     1     0     0      0      0      1       0.9
    0     0     0     1     0      1      0      0       1.0
```

Do I need a `dictvectorizer` from `sklearn`? If yes, then is there a way to convert original dataframe to dictionary which can be given to `dictvectorizer` which will in turn give me the encoded dataset as shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) If values in columns `user` or `item` are numeric, cast to `string` by  [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': {0: 13, 1: 11, 2: 14, 3: 12}, 
                   'affinity': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.9, 3: 1.0},
                   'user': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}},
                    columns=['user','item','affinity'])
print df
   user  item  affinity
0     1    13       0.1
1     2    11       0.4
2     3    14       0.9
3     4    12       1.0

df1 = df.user.astype(str).str.get_dummies()
df1.columns = ['user' + str(x) for x in df1.columns]
print df1
   user1  user2  user3  user4
0      1      0      0      0
1      0      1      0      0
2      0      0      1      0
3      0      0      0      1

df2 = df.item.astype(str).str.get_dummies()
df2.columns = ['item' + str(x) for x in df2.columns]
print df2
   item11  item12  item13  item14
0       0       0       1       0
1       1       0       0       0
2       0       0       0       1
3       0       1       0       0

print pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
   user1  user2  user3  user4  item11  item12  item13  item14  affinity
0      1      0      0      0       0       0       1       0       0.1
1      0      1      0      0       1       0       0       0       0.4
2      0      0      1      0       0       0       0       1       0.9
3      0      0      0      1       0       1       0       0       1.0
```

**Timings**:

`len(df) = 4`:

```
In [49]: %timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
The slowest run took 4.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 690 µs per loop
```

`len(df) = 40`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10).reset_index(drop=True)

In [51]: %timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
The slowest run took 5.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 719 µs per loop
```

`len(df) = 400`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True)

In [43]: %timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
The slowest run took 4.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 748 µs per loop
```

`len(df) = 4k`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [41]: %timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
The slowest run took 4.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 761 µs per loop
```

`len(df) = 40k`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop
```

`len(df) = 400k`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit pd.concat([df1,df2, df.affinity], axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Cool! Will this scale in terms of running time for a large dataset?

Comment: Hmmm, get dummies need much memory in large dataframe. Is it problem?

Comment: Currently memory won't be an issue as I can encode features one-at-a-time and save it to file, etc. But I am wondering about the time it will take. I will do some benchmarking and will post the results here, anyway.

Comment: I add some timings, please check it.